# YouTube enable old layout

Tags: youtube

I am not happy with the new YouTube layout:

> [image: bad]

it is very slow to load compared to the old version. Can I switch back to the
old version somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find an option anymore in the UI, but you can add a cookie to enable
the old layout (case sensitive):

```
document.cookie = 'PREF=f6=8';
```

> [image: good]

You can also use this expanded cookie to disable autoplay and default to "list"
layout:

```
document.cookie = 'PREF=cvdm=list&f5=30030&f6=8';
```